# XSLT transform with multiple XML input files

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

Is it possible to perform a transform on multiple input XML files?

It doesn't appear to be possible using `XslCompiledTransform`, but is there an alternative way of applying an XSLT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [XSL function document()](http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp) in your XSLT to reference an external XML file.

Comment: +1. If the input XML files cannot be modified, create a "wrapper" XML document that references all input files using `document()`.

Answer (score 4):

- Apply the transformation to each input XML file individually and compose the resulting XML documents into a single document.
- Compose the input XML files into a single document and apply the transformation, e.g.

```
XElement root = new XElement("root",
    XElement.Load("file1.xml"),
    XElement.Load("file2.xml"),
    XElement.Load("file3.xml"));

XslCompiledTransform transform;
transform.Transform(root.CreateReader(), output);
```

Answer (score 0):

With XSL function some security settings are necessary in C#. I believe this is the correct solution:

```
<xsl:include href="Filename"/>
```

This method handles multiple files.